# Select Hash Value when Key is an Array

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that has some keys as an array like so:

```
foo = {[45, 121]=>:some_field}
```

How can I select :some_field where a foo key contains 45?

And secondary to that, if it finds a match, how do I retrieve the other elements in the same key?

Comment: Your hash is oddly backwards. Typically `:some_field` would be the key, and the value would be an array to which you append additional numbers. I can't say for certain that it you're using it incorrectly as there is absolutely no context, but an `array=>symbol` hash is not often as useful as `symbol=>array`.

Comment: How is the hash constructed? Can you change it for much more efficient lookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can do this, it kind of defeats the purpose of using a hash since you will have to do a linear scan through the entire thing. It would be a lot better to have multiple hash keys for the same value since you can use the hash as an index then.

Example:

```
found = foo.find { |k, v| k.include?(n) }
found and found[1]
```

Keep in mind the performance of this will be *terrible* if you have large numbers of entries in the key and a large number of items in the hash since it will have to test against all keys and all values individually.

Comment: Actually, I would be ok with re-processing foo such that 45 and 121 are unique keys and I just copy :some_field to each. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = {[45, 121]=>:some_field}
foo.detect{ |k,v| k.include? 45 }
#=> [[45, 121], :some_field]
foo.detect{ |k,v| k.include? 45 }.last
#=> :some_field
```

Comment: While this works, it is as bad as walking an array looking for the results.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to reverse your hash if it's not one element only:

```
foo = {[45, 121]=>:some_field, [1, 45, 7] => :some_other_field}

bar = {}
foo.each do |k, v|
  k.each do |x|
    if bar.has_key?(x)
      bar[x] << [[k, v]]
    else
      bar[x] = [[k, v]]
    end
  end
end

p bar[45]
```